Spring Boot with JdbcTemplate reading 100 column eventually turn into 'Resultset is closed'
Here are my code snippets
package com.org.repository;

import com.org.config.datasourceconfig.DataSourceConfig;
import com.org.domain.transformer.SimpleMapper;
import com.org.infra.projection.SimpleProjection;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.*;

@Slf4j
@Repository
public class MyJDBCRepository extends AbstractJdbcRepository {

    public MyJDBCRepository(DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig) {
        super(dataSourceConfig);
    }

    public SimpleProjection findBy(
            Integer search1,
            Integer search2){
        String query = SQL_QUERY;

        boolean hasCondition = query.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).contains("where");
        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(query);

        hasCondition = appendEqualToClause(queryBuilder, hasCondition,  "a.column1", search1);
        hasCondition = appendEqualToClause(queryBuilder, hasCondition,  "a.column2 ", search2);
        
        queryBuilder.append(" limit 1");//TODO: This is temp change since we dont have `TimeStamp` type of column in reporting tables.

        log.info("createPreparedStatement [SQL Query]: {} ", queryBuilder);

        List<Object> params = new ArrayList<>();
        if (search1!= null) {
            params.add(search1);
        }
        if (search1 != null) {
            params.add(search2);
        }
        
        try {
            return getReadJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(queryBuilder.toString(), params.toArray(), new SimpleMapper());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception in searchApplications Query: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean appendEqualToClause(StringBuilder queryBuilder, boolean hasCondition, String columnName, Object value) {
    if (value != null) {
        queryBuilder.append(hasCondition ? " AND " : " WHERE ")
                .append(columnName)
                .append(" = ?");
        return true; // Return true to update hasCondition
    }
    return hasCondition; // If no condition is added, return the same value
}

This is Mapper
package com.org.domain.transformer;

import com.org.infra.projection.SimpleProjection;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Slf4j
public class SimpleMapper implements RowMapper<SimpleProjection> {

    @Override
    public SimpleProjection mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return new SimpleProjection() {
            @Override
            public Long getColumn1() {
                try {
                    return rs.getLong("column1");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    log.error("1. Reading column name failed : {}", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getColumn2() {
                try {
                    return rs.getString("column2");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    log.error("2. Reading column name failed : {}", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            :: ::
            :: ::

            @Override
            public Integer getColumn99() {
                try {
                    return rs.getInt("column99");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    log.error("99. Reading column name failed : {}", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Integer getColumn100() {
                try {
                    return rs.getInt("column100");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    log.error("100. Reading column name failed : {}", e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}

Note: I haven't posted the entire class because it has a lot of lines, so I posted a simplified version.
Projection interface
package com.org.infra.projection;

public interface SimpleProjection {

    Integer getColumn1();
    Integer getColumn2();
    
    :: ::
    :: ::
    
    Integer getColumn99();
    Integer getColumn100();
}

This is my DataSourceConfiguration
public DataSource readDataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(dataBaseDriver);
    config.setJdbcUrl(readDataBaseUrl);
    config.setUsername(readDataBaseUser);
    config.setPassword(readDataBasePassword);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(readMaximumPoolSize);
    config.setIdleTimeout(readIdleTimeout);
    config.setMinimumIdle(readMinimumIdle);
    config.setIdleTimeout(readIdleTimeout);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(readConnectionTimeout);
    config.setMaxLifetime(readMaxLifeTime);
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}

with its properties
spring.datasource.read.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.read.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.read.hikari.idle-timeout=10000
spring.datasource.read.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.read.hikari.max-lifetime=60000

While executing, I get:
74. Reading column name failed : This ResultSet is closed.
46. Reading column name failed : This ResultSet is closed.

What I did is comment out or didn't read after 50th column, and for those it is giving me data, from 41st column it is giving me an error "Resultset is Closed" this is my finding.
Any help or let me know what's wrong I am doing here?

Why don't you try to use Specifications or Criteria API for this, you won't have to build your queries manually.

Please provide the exception stacktrace.

And specify the database and JDBC driver you're using. Also, although simplifying your code is helpful, you'll still need to provide a [mre], and your current code isn't one.

Stacktrace: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.checkClosed(PgResultSet.java:3242)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:3080)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getInt(PgResultSet.java:2945)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at com.org.domain.transformer.SummDiscomOverviewSdoMapper$1.getColumn99(SimpleMapper.java

Drivers and DB: spring.datasource.read.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/DEV?currentSchema=plana
spring.datasource.read.username=postgres
spring.datasource.read.password=postgres
spring.datasource.read.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

This is by the way AWS Read replica Postgres DB
